# Bs4 is returning "[]" how do I go about fixing this error?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to make a code that identifies if they search the use has inputted returns a blank page or not and I am doing this by identifying if there is certain text on the screen

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = input("Input the domain of the top level domain: ")
textsearch = input("Input what text you're looking for: ")

r = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A.{site}+%22{textsearch}%22")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
search = soup.find_all(text="Try different keywords")
print(search)
```

The problem is this code is returning "[]" when I know this web page returns zero results, how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: why not print r.text and see what it has? I just did it for you ... i find no elements where the text is "Try different keywords" but i do see something containing that text (in addition to other text) why not just `"Try different keywords" in r.text`?

Comment: Yeah I actually did see this but I must've looked at it incorrectly and this worked, thank you!

Comment: I couldn't find anything definitive in the BS docs, but if you make that a regular expression, you'll find the text node. `search = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Try different keywords"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you need to do is see if that phrase is present anywhere then you do not need bs4

just do `if "Try different keywords" in r.text: print("ERROR no results")`